# Graph API - How long using facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Graph API (PHP), How to find how long a user is using facebook? Or from when a user is using facebook?

Comment: What? Do you mean the sign-up date?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly the sign up date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to get the sign-up date directly (someone please correct me if I'm wrong or this gets added in the future). I've been using FQL to pull the oldest thing out of the user's feed and using the `updated_time` as an approximate sign-up date.

Comment: Can you give me any example to get the oldest feed?

Comment: If I do that, it will mean looking at work stuff, and I'll get caught up with work stuff and forget to give you teh codez. See how far you can get and I'll try to remember to get back to you after work.

Comment: generally I know how to get the latest feed from a user. What kind of information can we get from sql apart from status updates, Picture uploading, likes and comments?

Comment: The FQL stuff is basically SQL. The FB docs are currently confusing; they talk about FQL in the context of the old REST API, but you're really meant to use it with the Graph API. Anyway, [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20created_time%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20%3D%20100001932675863%20ORDER%20BY%20created_time%20ASC%20LIMIT%201) should get you headed in the right direction.